# Toggle an Image on top of my background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Starting to learn some HTML, CSS, and JQuery. It's pretty fun and user-friendly, but I'm having some trouble with parts of it. I have an image set as the background and it has some white stars on it. I have an image of a gold star that is the same size and positioned it right on top of one of the blank stars. I want to use the toggle method to show and hide the gold star when clicked on. I've looked at a lot of questions in on stack overflow and other sites, and to me it seems like it should be working, and I'm not getting any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Fixed the code, its working now!

CSS code

```
   #toggle {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:109px;
    width:37px;
    height:37px;
    z-index:1;
}

#imgStar1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:1px;
    top:-1px;
    width:38px;
    height:38px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML and JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainLayout.css" type="text/css" />

<style>
    #bkgd {
        background: url('images/recents.png') 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 806px;
        height: 481px;
        z-index=-1
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
            $("#imgStar1").toggle();
        });

    });



</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="toggle">
    <img id="imgStar1" src="images/star1.png" alt="star1" width="37" height="37"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having wrong id:

In html img's id is `picStar1` not `imgStar1`, so change that...

Plus, you should not use the same id for multiple times. Id should be unique.

To solve:

Just change the img id in html `picStar1` with `imgStar1` and should work fine.

Comment: plus, he should make sure that the `z-index` of `picStar1` is higher than that of `imgStar1`

Comment: Yes, but there should not be any problem with z-index as div is background and img is absolutely positioned and nowhere z-index is applied, anyway for OP should use higher z-index value for img....

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah I'm really confusing myself with classes and ID's. Your fix worked, @C-linkNepal, but once I click and it hides, it doesn't show when I click again. Is this because it is behind the background now?

Comment: I added the z-index values for both background and image. It still only toggles once. And would there be a way to start it off hidden and make it appear on click? Cause the toggle doesn't work when I use, display:none;

Comment: I'm unsure with your html markup for ids... Did you change id for img only or for both??

Comment: What you were having the code when you asked in that just change the id for img as I said and let me know if that works...

Comment: And I'm pretty sure if first time appears on top then after click should also appear on top, You're just having problem with the id....

Comment: I changed all my ID's to imgStar1. I edited the code above so that its what I'm trying right now and it still disappearing after I click on it once and won't show again.

Comment: OK got it to work. Added another div for toggle. Thanks for your help!